# Danish localization when publishing app

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to figure out how to localize the title and description of our app in Danish, English and German.

When i add a new app in itunes connects it asks me to enter the information in english. When i then go to manage localizations i only get a limited list of languages to add - Danish is NOT one of them.

I read the iTunes connect developer guide which mentions the following: "This is in addition to the English (or other default language you set on your defaults page) metadata you’ve 
already supplied during your initial app creation."

But i can't find anywhere to set Danish as the default language to then get the option to add english and german as extra languages.

So how do i go about making sure that my app is available with a local title and description in the Danish store as well as the english and german stores?
Any help is GREATLY appreciated since I can't seem to get an answer from Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunaly you cannot change the default language as far as I know (and this has created some major headache for developers in the past as the default language appears in ALL stores that have no custom language. If you for example chose your native language instead of english, you will have that displayed all over the world and can create a lot of exceptions for the countries in the list). (**Edit** since recently the default language can be changed per App)

As for the language list: you only get what is there and have to rely on apple to extend the list in the future (never a bad idea to send en enhancement request).

Unfortunaly probably not what you wanted to hear but localization handling is still somewhat suboptimal. The only thing you can do is enter the information in the default language in Danish (and thus create a danish page for some parts of the world as well) and fill ALL of the other languages with a localized description (or english if you cannot localize) which at least gives an english description for some of the larger markets.

I'm not sure how/if Apple allows the default description in Danish if the setting is English but I already had to fill all localizations in the list with english text (even Japanese, French etc.) and had the app approved.

Comment: I was afraid of getting that answer.
So a possible solution could be to publish the app multiple times for different regions. Say publish the app for only Denmark with danish as the language and then do a secondary publish of the app for every other country in the world in english?

Comment: I suppose that could work as long as apple plays along. You'd have to register two different names and app IDs though to have the app on the store twice.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pain no matter what option i end up choosing. But having Danish shown in the US appstore because i enter Danish as the default text is just bad bad bad.

Comment: You can set the language for at least the major stores individually, e.g. North America, parts on europe, japan etc. At least those "larger" markets will get an english description then but there will be a lot of countries with the danish one.

Comment: I can't add anything for the US - It's not on the list. There is Australian english, UK english and then just "english" which is the default language. And i assume that the default english option is the one being used in the US store.

Comment: I suppose that would be the US version, yes. Note that recently there was an option added to change the default language per app, although this might not help you in this case as long as there is no Dutch on the list...

Comment: Yeah, I got a mail about that a few days ago. So lets say i choose "Italian" as the default language and enter english for all the other languages. Does that mean that the Italian version will be displayed in all iTunes stores which don't have a specific language option? Or will the italian version only be shown in Italy and the english option will still take precedense for other countries not on the list?

Comment: The default language will be displayed in all countries that do not have a specific localization set for them. Thus in your case the Italian version would be displayed all over the world except for those that have specific localizations (I have not yet found an official mapping of languages to countries).